# ActiveRecord include or join has_one records on where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

With following model

user.rb

```
# Columns
# job_title :string
#  (..)

has_one :spec
```

spec.rb

```
# Columns
# org_unit :string
# department :string
# room_number :string

belongs_to :user
```

.. I'm able to write:

```
irb(main):005:0> user.spec.department
  Spec Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "specs".* FROM "specs" WHERE "specs"."user_id" = ?
    LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> front-end
```

But now I'd like to do a search on both classes like:

```
User.where(job_title: "developer").where(self.spec.department: "front-end")
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
User.where(job_title: "developer").joins(:spec).where(specs: {department: "front-end"})
```

Comment: Right. Edited my answer.

Comment: Readable and exactly working solution. Thank you very much!